# HTML button causing unwanted page load

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I feel with this particular problem I have to explain how my webpage works, otherwise it might not make sense to anyone. The page will load, you will be given some text and the option to click on a asp.net combobox filled with options, when you select one of them, the page will reload and get all the information in relation to that user and display it in a dynamically created HTML table.

After this there are two divs that runat server and dependent on if the user has uploaded a file will display an option of changing the file, or adding a new one.

I have a standard html button that when is clicked is meant to run my JavaScript function, but when you click on the button it fires my aspxcombobox code again. I will attach all my code that I feel might be useful.

HTML for DIVS

```
     <div id ="upload" runat = "server" visible = "false" class="default">
         <asp:Label ID="uploadlbl" runat="server" Text="Upload driving licence" style="color:Red"></asp:Label>
         <dx:ASPxUploadControl ID="LicenceUpload" runat="server">
         </dx:ASPxUploadControl>

         <dx:ASPxButton ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload" style="margin-left: 2px">
         </dx:ASPxButton>
     </div>

     <div id="ChangeUpload" runat="server"  visible="false" class="default">
        <span>Licence already uploaded</span>
        <br />
        <button id="changeLicence" onclick="changeLicence()">Change Licence?</button>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function changeLicence() {
   alert('test'); 
}
```

Comment: default behavior of `button` is submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a submit button. It submits the form it is in. Since you are using ASP.NET, the entire page is probably in a form.

Add `type="button"` to make it a non-submit button.

Answer (score 1):

default behavior of `button` is submit, Add `type="button"` attribute so that it doesn't submits form.

```
<button 
    type="button" 
    id="changeLicence" 
    onclick="changeLicence()">Change Licence?</button>
```